# how to change a value of a cell that contains nan to another specific value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe that contains nan values in particular column. while iterating through the rows, if it come across `nan`(using `isnan()` method) then I need to change it to some other value(since I have some conditions). I tried using `replace()` and `fillna()` with `limit` parameter also but they are modifying whole column when they come across the first `nan` value? Is there any method that I can assign value to specific `nan` rather than changing all the values of a column?

Example: the dataframe looks like it:

```
  points  sundar    cate  king  varun  vicky  john  charlie  target_class
1     x2       5   'cat'     4     10      3     2        1           NaN
2     x3       3   'cat'     1      2      3     1        1           NaN
3     x4       6  'lion'     8      4      3     7        1           NaN
4     x5       4  'lion'     1      1      3     1        1           NaN
5     x6       8   'cat'    10     10      9     7        1           0.0
```

an I have a list like

```
a = [1.0, 0.0]
```

and I expect to be like

```
  points  sundar    cate  king  varun  vicky  john  charlie  target_class
1     x2       5   'cat'     4     10      3     2        1           1.0
2     x3       3   'cat'     1      2      3     1        1           1.0
3     x4       6  'lion'     8      4      3     7        1           1.0
4     x5       4  'lion'     1      1      3     1        1           0.0
5     x6       8   'cat'    10     10      9     7        1           0.0
```

I wanted to change the target_class values based on some conditions and assign values of the above list.

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Comment: Sure. I will. :-)

Comment: `based on some conditions` - Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you think something like if column `cate` is `cat` then `nan` should be replace to `1` else `nan` replaced to `0`?

Comment: No. the condition is not related to any other column in the dataset. the condition related to the clustering results and score of it . Based on the score(say like some threshold), it has to decide either 1.0 or 0.0

Comment: so basically I iterate through indexes in the clustering result and look up for those index in the dataframe then I use threshold to assign value(either 1.0 or 0.0)

Answer (score 1):

I believe need replace `NaN`s values to `1` only for indexes specified in list `idx`:

```
mask = df['target_class'].isnull()
idx = [1,2,3]
df.loc[mask, 'target_class'] = df[mask].index.isin(idx).astype(int)
print (df)
  points  sundar    cate  king  varun  vicky  john  charlie  target_class
1     x2       5   'cat'     4     10      3     2        1           1.0
2     x3       3   'cat'     1      2      3     1        1           1.0
3     x4       6  'lion'     8      4      3     7        1           1.0
4     x5       4  'lion'     1      1      3     1        1           0.0
5     x6       8   'cat'    10     10      9     7        1           0.0
```

Or:

```
idx = [1,2,3]
s = pd.Series(df.index.isin(idx).astype(int), index=df.index)
df['target_class'] = df['target_class'].fillna(s)
```

EDIT:

From comments solution is assign values by index and columns values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2.loc['x2', 'target_class'] = list1[0]
```

Comment: @Vamshi - So need `df2.loc['x2', 'target_class'] = 1` ?

Comment: yes. something like that. `df2.loc['x2']['target_class']` will return nan (when I consider points column as the index). Then I wrote df2.loc['x2']['target_class']=list1[0] and tried to assign the value from list. But when I saw the output of df2.loc['x2']['target_class'] it gave me the same nan value.

Comment: I think that I am not creating a copy of the dataframe or what ?

Comment: @Vamshi - Exactly, you are right. But working solution is add only `[]` and use `loc` like `df2.loc['x2', 'target_class'] = list1[0]`

Comment: @Vamshi - It is called chained assignments, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: yeah now its working. thank you. I guess I need to change the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your conditions for imputing the `nan` values does not depend on the number of them in a column. In the code below I stored all the imputation rules in one function that receives as parameters the entire row (containing the `nan`) and the column you are investigating for. If you also need all the dataframe for the imputation rules, just pass it through the `replace_nan` function. In the example I imputate the `col` element with the mean values of the other columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def replace_nan(row, col):
    row[col] = row.drop(col).mean()
    return row

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

col_to_impute = 'col1'
df.loc[[1, 3], col_to_impute] = np.nan

df = df.apply(lambda x: replace_nan(x, col_to_impute) if np.isnan(x[col_to_impute]) else x, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you should do is making the right assignation. That is, make an assignation in the rows that contain nulls.

Example dataset:

```
,event_id,type,timestamp,label
0,asd12e,click,12322232,0.0
1,asj123,click,212312312,0.0
2,asd321,touch,12312323,0.0
3,asdas3,click,33332233,
4,sdsaa3,touch,33211333,
```

Note: The last two rows contains nulls in column: 'label'. Then, we load the dataset:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
```

Now, we make the appropiate condition:

```
cond = df['label'].isnull()
```

Now, we make the assignation over these rows (I don't know the logical of assignation. Therefore I assign 1 value to NaN's):

```
df1.loc[cond,'label'] = 1
```

There are another more accurate approaches. fillna() method could be used. You should provide the logical in order to help you.

Comment: I think `df['label'] = df['label'].fillna(1)` is better, but OP need somehing different. Sometimes replace NaNs to `0` or to `1`.

Comment: For the example that I have provided I totally agree. But I don't know if the OP needs to add another condition and how to implement correctly in fillna() method.